# How can I download a lower resolution image from an image URL? I have no control on the server side

Tags: wget, curl

So, I see that we can use -r range in curl. Is there any way that instead of downloading a complete image from the URL(someone else's), I could just use lower bandwidth and get lower resolution image, by reconstructing the parts downloaded by curl?

Comment: With curl it's impossible. Use opera turbo mode which exactly does what you want. http://help.opera.com/Mac/11.60/en/turbo.html

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. Opera works by utilising their own server-side compression proxy, I believe chroms offers a similar add-on using google servers.